# How to convert unichar to int (ord function) in Vala?

Tags: vala

I found no method to achieve this function in its API: http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/unichar

I mean get the character's unicode value something like ord('A') = 65 in other languages.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unichar -> int**

'a' -> 97

```
unichar a = 'a';
int ia = (int)a;
```

'0' -> 0:

```
unichar num = '0';
string? str = num.to_string ();
if (str != null) {
    stdout.printf("%d\n", int.parse (str));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clearly describing the question. I want something like ord('a') => 97. Not paring a numeric string to int.

Comment: @CameronWong Oh, I see. Doesn't simple `int ia = (int)a;` work in Vala?

Comment: I used `printf("%d", c)` before and it complains error. I didn't know I just need a strong conversion `printf("%d", (int)c)`. So stupid I am...

Comment: @CameronWong Great!  Updated my answer